# function for loading an image from internet in an imageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to make a function to load an image in an imageView at runtime.
Can you help making it work?

Here the complete code: (Swift 3)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as Data? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            })
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed to resume(`resume()`) the data task.

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as Data? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```